# How to create new instance from a snapshot and a new OS version

Tags: amazon-web-services, update, snapshot, operating-system, amazon-lightsail

I have a NodeJS instance on Amazon LightSail. I want to upgrade the underlying Operating System to a newer major version, say Ubuntu 18 LTS to Ubuntu 20 LTS.

When I create a new instance from the snapshot, I do not get the option of choosing the version of the OS, so the new instance will have the same OS ad the original instance.

Is it possible, from a snapshot running a previous OS version, to create an instance with a newer OS version? If not, is there an easy way to upgrade the OS of an instance, short of creating a new instance, installing programs and transferring data?

Comment: A newer version of the *same* operating system, or an entirely different OS? Typically there's an upgrade path for, say, Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10, but you're in very different territory if you wanna go Ubuntu to Centos. Both will require work on your end, though.

Comment: It's for a newer major version of the OS, say Ubuntu 18 LTS to Ubuntu 20 LTS. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you've asked isn't possible. A snapshot is an image of a disk. You can't upgrade the OS while creating an instance from a snapshot.

If you want to upgrade your operating system create an instance from the snapshot then follow the instructions from the provider of the OS. Ubuntu, for example, makes it [simple to upgrade](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/upgrade-introduction). To upgrade from Ubuntu 18 to 20 you [follow the documentation](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today).

Comment: Thank you Tim. I updated the question: it's for example Ubuntu 18 LTS to Ubuntu 20 LTS.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer slightly. Short answer: snapshots are snapshots, upgrades are upgrades, they're separate. Create the instance then run the upgrade.

Comment: In my case, it was simpler to create a new virtual machine with the newer operating system, installing programs, and migrating the data to it. Upgrading the original virtual machine led to many questions about packages and compatibility, and I got tired of it.

Comment: I did the same a couple of years back. Amazon Linux 1 was annoying to use, not many packages available for it, so I moved to Ubuntu, installed software, moved data, wasn't too difficult.